# Flutter: faster way to use MediaQuery

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want know is there any shortcut that I can use for MediaQuery.

for Example, when I want width of screen I do like

`final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;`

now I every time I have to divide the required width with the screen width like `100/375 =0.266` and then do this `width * 0.266`

is there any shortcut that I can avoid the `dividing` part so that I can just write required pixels and it will automatically calculate everything?

Answer (score 4):

There is a flutter package that you could use, which divides the screen effectively in percentages. The package name is [sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer). In this package, you have some pre-defined parameters such as:

- `.h` - (double) for widget height
- `.w` - (double) for widget width
- `.sp` - (double) for font size

For whatever size you define a widget, it would take a percentage of it, for example:

```
Container(
  height: 20.0.h,  //It will take a 20% of screen height
  width: 40.0.w    //It will take a 40% of screen width
)
```

Comment: but if I want `5/375` wouldn't I have to remember the percentage of `5/375` because in the design we are given the pixels not percentage

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FractionallySizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html) widget to make your child widget take up a fraction of the available space.

```
FractionallySizedBox(
  widthFactor: 0.5,
  heightFactor: 0.4
  child:  RaisedButton(
    child: Text('Click'),
    color: Colors.green,
    textColor: Colors.white,
    onPressed: () {
    },
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double calculated (int pixels) {
return width * pixels/375;
}

//in your code:

Container ( width: calculated (100),
                    child: Text('hi')
                   )
```